# Django: How Can I get 'pk' in views.py when I use class based views?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm writhing an app with class based views. I need to receive 'pk' in my views.py file when I load my page using generic DetailView.

My urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . views import HomeView, ProfileView, AddPetView, EditPetView, DeletePetView, 
PetProfileView

urlpatterns = [
...
path('profile/pet/<int:pk>', PetProfileView.as_view(), name='pet_profile'),
path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

My views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, UpdateView, CreateView, DeleteView, 
DetailView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from . models import Pet

class PetProfileView(DetailView):
    model = Pet
    template_name = 'pet_profile.html'
    #key = Pet.objects.values_list('birth_date').get(pk=1)
```

My Pet Model is:

```
class Pet(models.Model):
pet_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
pet_breed = models.CharField(max_length=255)
pet_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
pet_reg_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True) # when the pet is registered in the site
birth_date = models.DateField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.pet_name + ' | ' + str(self.owner)

# def get_absolute_url(self):
#   return reverse('article-detail', args=str(self.id))
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('profile')
```

When I load profile for some pet, I need to get in my view class PetProfileView(DetailView): like a variable the birth date for this specific pet. I will make some calculations with this date

I need to extract from database birh_date column for this specific pet. How to get this pk=? when I load pet_profile page?

I'm not sure if I can describe the case well. If something is not clear, ask me. I will try to explain again.

Comment: Can you share your `Pet` model in the question and elaborate somewhat what kind of queryset do you exactly want from pk?

Answer (score 1):

On class based views:

```
self.kwargs['pk']
```

So, in your case

```
class PetProfileView(DetailView):
    model = Pet
    template_name = 'pet_profile.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context['key'] = self.get_object().birth_date
        return context
```

I don't know what you want to do with the "key" variable. This example is to use on your template. You can access to "birth_date" writting `{{key}}` or `{{object.birth_date}}`

Comment: Hi @LaCharcaSoftware,
If I write it like this
"def get_key(self):
        Pet.objects.values_list('birth_date').get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
key = self.get_key()
" I receive error in the terminal. 
"
File "/opt/django/petpassport/passport/views.py", line 27, in <module>
    class PetProfileView(DetailView):
  File "/opt/django/petpassport/passport/views.py", line 39, in PetProfileView
    key = get_key()
TypeError: get_key() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

"

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you can access the URL parameters like `self.kwargs["pk"]`. But as you are already using a `DetailView` which already provides the functionality to retrieve an object via its id you can customize the queryset it uses:

```
class PetProfileView(DetailView):
    model = Pet
    template_name = 'pet_profile.html'
    queryset = Pet.objects.values_list('birth_date')
```

(Though without doing this you should also be able to access `pet.birth_date` in your template)

Comment: It should be `self.get_object().values_list('birth_date')`, shouldn't be?

Comment: The  `DetailView` will use the `queryset` to fetch the object from, no need to change the order (and `get_object()` returns as the name says an object not a queryset)...

Comment: @LaCharcaSoftware `self` is always used inside the method we make in classes, it's a python concept, we can't use self outside the methods in classes.

Comment: Hi @BernhardVallant,
If I use "queryset = Pet.objects.values_list('birth_date')", I receive birth dates for all pets in the table. I need this date like a variable in the class PetProfileView in views.py, because i will make some calculations with it.